# How to combine two filepaths (as strings) removing extra "/" in C++

Tags: c++, string

The user enters as a basepath "test/" or he enters "test". Now I want to store dataset A in "test/dataA/file1.dat" etc. and dataset B in "test/dataB/file1.dat" etc.

Since I do not know if the user enters "test" or "test/" I should check if there is a "/" at the end or not to combine the strings correctly.

How can I do this in a short and clean way?

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;    

int main() {
    string user1 = "test";
    string user2 = "test/";

    string relativeFilePath = "/dataA/data.dat";

    /*
    cout << f(user1, relativeFilePath) << endl; //should return "test/dataA/data.dat"
    cout << f(user2, relativeFilePath) << endl; //should return the same

    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: more cleaner than `user2[user2.Size()-1] == L"/"` ?

Comment: why on earth does your relative path start with a `/` ?

Comment: … the **correct** way is not to muck around with strings but rather to manipulate path objects. Boost.Filesystem for instance implements this. Repeat after me: paths are not strings. They just look like strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
user2[user2.Size()-1] == L"/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating `std::string` so you can take advantage of function that it provides (`back` return a reference to the last character, `pop_back()` erase the last character):

```
if (!user2.empty() && user2.back()=='/') user2.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a function, `trim_trailing_slash`.

```
void trim_trailing_slash(std::string& s)
{
   // Remove all trailing slashes.
   while ( !s.empty() && s.back() == '/' )
   {
      s.pop_back();
   }
}
```

and then use it in `f`.

```
std::string f(std::string const& user, std::string const& relativeFilePath)
{
   std::string ret = user;
   trim_trailing_slash(ret);
   ret += relativeFilePath;
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, you could also make use of [`string::replace`]  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

or

[`string::erase`] (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) to accomplish this.